# Display rows after having (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c, having

I have below select (it will be more union):

```
select column_name,'my_table', count(*)
from my_table
where col10 = 'TEST' 
group by column_name
having count(*) > 1

union all

select column_name,'my_table2', count(*)
from my_table2
where col10 = 'TEST' 
group by column_name
having count(*) > 1

union all...;
```

After run the statement I got **0 rows from my_table2**.

It's possible then to display something like below??

[image]

Comment: use `not exists`

Comment: I'm not sure this query can return such results. Perhaps you did overlook something in the original query when translating it to the version you typed...

My other guess is that having is messing with the execution plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another `UNION ALL` for each table

```
union all

select '-', 'my_table2', 0
from dual
where not exists
(
  select 1
  from my_table2
  where col10 = 'TEST' 
  group by column_name
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: thx, it's working....first select is created some temporary (dual) space?

Comment: @4est dual is an auxiliary table with one row in oracle. it is used in such cases as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select nvl(sq.column_name, '-') as column_name, tn.table_name,
       nvl(sq."count > 1", 0)   as "count > 1"
from   ( 
         select "my_table"  as table_name from dual union all
         select "my_table2"               from dual -- [ ... union all ... etc]
       ) tn
     left outer join
       (
         -- ENTER YOUR CURRENT QUERY HERE, AS A SUBQUERY
       ) sq
       on tn.table_name = sq.table_name
;
```

Comment: for me this is too complex, I prefer use @Radim solution, but thank you anyway